# How to click on a coordinate on a screen?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a program that wants to be able to click on the screen; say my screen is X by Y pixels, I want to make my program send clicks to coordinate (x, y).  Any language is acceptable, but preferably Ruby, Java, or Python :)

Preferably on Windows, Ubuntu is another possibility.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please see my post.  I edited it to say Windows, or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu:

```
from Xlib import X, display

disp = display.Display()
screen = disp.screen()
root = screen.root
root.warp_pointer(300, 300)
disp.sync()
```

So as a function:

```
from Xlib import X, display

def MoveMouse(x, y):
  disp = display.Display()
  screen = disp.screen()
  root = screen.root
  root.warp_pointer(x, y)
  disp.sync()
```

I'll edit in `click` functionality in a little bit...

---

Holy cow, just *look* at the `help(root)`! You can draw things, change the cursor, fiddle with windows, *and* kill X!

I'm using this for my own purposes...

Answer (score 1):

I would give a short answer to your question, but I believe that [this article here](http://www.1your.com/drupal/robotclassdemo) explains things a lot better than I would and would be much more beneficial. It's in Java and goes over the Robot class which is good for input simulations, mainly for things such as tech demos where the robot class substitutes for real user input. It's fairly in depth, short, and is a really easy read. Hope you enjoy!